# Xamarin SqlLite database in Android Internal shared storage

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

My application will be used offline and I plan daily pull/push synchronizations via USB cable.  My users are in a very primitive situation: no wifi, and no cell phone towers.  My question is not about synchronization, but rather just getting access to the data so that I can synchronize.

I connect the cable, select USB for file transfer, and I can see Internal Shared Storage.  But I cannot find my SqlLite database anywhere.  I have tried using these paths for the database:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData); 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
Android.App.Application.Context.FilesDir.AbsolutePath;
```

The app works fine with any of those paths, the data is stored and retrieved, but I cannot see the database from my PC.

I have also tried this but it blows up:

```
Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;
```

I have tried debugging with Xamarin Live but then I get this error:

> "You need to call SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider();"

I have tried adding `console.writeline` and `Log.Error` to add in some diagnostics but I can't find any log files in Internal Shared Storage.

I have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions in the manifest; even tho I think that is not necessary.

If I could store files in Internal Shared Storage then I could put the database there and access it to synchronize.  And I could create a simple text logging facility to write a text log to the same place.

I have rarely asked for help in 40 years but I've been at this for days.  Thanks!

Comment: Those locations are within your app's sandbox and thus are private and not available via `adb` (i.e. file transfer) unless your Android devices are rooted. You could store a copy of your sqlite db in a public external storage location (i.e. external to your app) and access it there.

Comment: From the laptop I can see "Internal Shared Storage", which is the same place as shown in File Explorer, Local, Internal Storage.  Lots of apps put files here: camera, whatsApp, Alarms, etc.  When I do it, it is not visible,

Comment: string extPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMusic).AbsolutePath;
            extPath = Path.Combine(extPath, "RtTrace.txt");
            File.AppendAllText(extPath, "text content" + Environment.NewLine);

Comment: I guess I have a solution for your problem. I faced a similar issue. I'll post it when getting home.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing the same challenge, I would like my users to be able to sync data between mobile and desktop via a connection cable but can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: No I was unable to do it.  Instead I used WiFI with a web service on the laptop.  I also did backup the database to a USB drive then plug the USB into the laptop and copy in.

Answer (score 0):

To get files onto Internal Shared Storage accessible via USB took 3 steps:
1:  Get runtime permissions
    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(activity, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 1);

2) use this path:
    string extPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
    extPath = Path.Combine(extPath, "RtTrace.txt");
    File.AppendAllText(extPath, "new content" + System.Environment.NewLine);

3) Media scan the resulting file to make it visible:
    MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Android.App.Application.Context, new String[] { extPath }, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

The path on `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` refers to a private area where only the app (and the OS itself when you clear data from the app, for example) have access. I don't know about `ApplicationData`.

You can easily copy your app file (the protected one) to a public folder, like `Downloads` or create a new folder `MyAppDirectory` at the public storage space, that will allow access from other devices. Then, you can clear local data that you don't need anymore (after the sync process).

To create a new public folder on Android:

```
var folder = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "MyAppDirectory");

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
```

You'll get this:

[image]

Then, copy the file:

```
var newFile = Path.Combine(folder, "MySharedFile"); // The database, xml, json, text or any file you want to share
var sourceFullName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"MyOriginalFile");

System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFullName, newFile, true /* overwrite */);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

SQLite db is stored in application private memory and can't be accessed over USB, try exporting contents of your DB to an external file in your internal memory or External memory to be able to access it via a USB chord.

Comment: I would love to, but I don't know how.  From the laptop I can see "Internal Shared Storage", which is the same place as shown in File Explorer, Local, Internal Storage. Lots of apps put files here: camera, whatsApp, Alarms, etc. When I do it, it is not visible: string extPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMusic).AbsolutePath; extPath = Path.Combine(extPath, "RtTrace.txt"); File.AppendAllText(extPath, "text content" + Environment.NewLine);